# change navigation on router events fired

Tags: javascript, angular

i want to change destination route after navigation start.
i've creating an app using angular i want if user click browser back button i change user navigation to home page. in my app.component i check navigation but router navigation doesn't fire:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
router.events.subscribe((val: NavigationStart) => {
      if (val.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
        router.navigate['home'];
      }
  });
}
```

is it a way to change destination route after router events fired?

Update:
my AppRoutingModule contain :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'account', loadChildren: () => import('./account/account.module').then(m => m.AccountModule)  },
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
  { path: 'notification', loadChildren:() => import('./notification/notification.module').then(x=> x.NotificationModule) }
];

....
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and my For Example NotificationRoutingModule :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NotificationComponent } from './notification.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail/detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '' ,component: NotificationComponent,children: [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'list', component: ListComponent},
    {path: 'detail/:id', component: DetailComponent}
  ]}
];

....
export class NotificationRoutingModule { }
```

and my HomeRoutindModule is contain :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '' ,  component : HomeComponent},
  {path: 'home' ,  component : HomeComponent},
];

....
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

i want if user went to navigation ('notification') after he press browser navigation i change next navigation whatever it was ,navigation change to something like 'home'.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(router: Router) {
router.events.subscribe((val: NavigationStart) => {
      if (val.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
        // if val.url equal '/notification/list'
        router.navigate['\home'];
        // i tried it but navigation does't changed
      }
  });
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

router navigation method give an array as commands and an object as extras object (**NavigationExtras interface**).and **NavigationExtras** interface has a property as **replaceUrl**
for replacing the current state whatever it was.then i changed my code to:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
router.events.subscribe((val: NavigationStart) => {
      if (val.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
        // here changed
        router.navigate(['home'], {replaceUrl:true});
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place Html component.html as

```
   <input type="button" name="" value="Back"  (click)="Home()" class="btn btn secondary"/>
```

Place component.ts as

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private router: Router){}
```

component.ts Method as

```
Home() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';
```

and then listening for popstate on the window object

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
   console.log('Back button pressed');
   // Here write navigation route
}
```

Comment: Navigation url doesn't change

Comment: Could you share your whole component code? (Only ts file)

Answer (score 0):

```
router.navigate(['/home'])
```

I replicated your code locally and made a change I hope this works.

Comment: I took the time to replicate your code, I went with the same concept you are using, Just change the `router.navigate['\home'];` line with `router.navigate(['/home']);` and it should work since it is tested.

Comment: thanks a lot. but when you are in Router it doesn't change url.i find out if i want to change router url when i subscribe router i should call replaceUrl in extras like : router.navigate(['home'], {replaceUrl:true});

Answer (score 0):

```
    yourFunction {
        this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
          if (ev instanceof NavigationStart && ev.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
            this.router.navigate(["home"]);
          }
        })
      }

 constructor(...) {
 this.yourFunction()
}
```